# SQL SUM and COUNT on Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have data in MS Access like:

```
+------------+-----------+
| DateStart  | PATIssued |
+------------+-----------+
| 12/12/2004 | Yes       |
+------------+-----------+
| 13/12/2004 | No        |
+------------+-----------+
| 14/12/2004 | No        |
+------------+-----------+
| 12/12/2004 | No        |
+------------+-----------+
| 12/12/2004 | Yes       |
+------------+-----------+
| 14/12/2004 | No        |
+------------+-----------+
| 13/12/2004 | Yes       |
```

I want to count number of records per day for the past week by day of week, and in another column count records where PATIssued = Yes

So the results would look like:

```
Date       DayCount PATCount
Monday        3        2
Tuesday       2        1
Wednesday     2        0
```

I have gotten as far as

```
SELECT Format(DateValue(DateStart),"dddd") AS DayOFWeek,  PATIssuedYN,
Count(Table1.DateStart) AS DayCount,
Sum(IIf([PATIssuedYN]="Yes",1,))
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.DateStart) Between DateAdd("d",-7,Now()) And Now()))
GROUP BY DateValue(DateStart), PATIssuedYN;
```

The problem is that this returns

```
Date       PATIssuedYN   DayCount PATCount
Monday        No            1         
Monday        Yes           2        2
Tuesday       No            1
Tuesday       Yes           1        1
Wednesday     No            2        
Wednesday     Yes           0        0
```

Where Monday is 12/12, Tuesday is 13/12 Wednesday is 14/12

Comment: remove `PATIssuedYN` from your select and group by

Comment: Use a condition, that PATIssuedYN = Yes

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко that would skew the `DayCount` value

Answer (score 2):

since you do not want to return column `PatIssuedYN`, remove it from your select and your group by:

```
SELECT Format(DateValue(DateStart),"dddd") AS DayOFWeek,
Count(Table1.DateStart) AS DayCount,
Sum(IIf([PATIssuedYN]="Yes",1,))
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.DateStart) Between DateAdd("d",-7,Now()) And Now()))
GROUP BY DateValue(DateStart);
```